# Код выдает NaN почему?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Accumulator(startingValue){
  this.startingValue = startingValue;
  this.read = function(){
    this.a = +prompt('Сколько будем прибавлять?', '');
  };
  this.value = 0 + this.a;
};

var accumulator = new Accumulator(1);


accumulator.read();
console.log( accumulator.value);
```

1. Создаем функцию конструктор с параметром startingValue
2. В теле функции ссылаемся на объект которому даем свойство startingValue
3. startingValue присваиваем аргумент 1
4. ссылаемся на объект которому даем функцию read
5. В read создаем +prompt которое спрашивает число
6. ссылаемся на объект которому даем свойство value
7. value присваиваем число 0 + число которое вел пользователь
8. Получать должны число
9. А по факту получаем NaN

```js
function Accumulator(startingValue) {
  this.value = startingValue;

  this.read = function() {
    this.value += +prompt('Сколько добавлять будем?', 0);
  };

}

var accumulator = new Accumulator(1);
accumulator.read();
accumulator.read();
alert( accumulator.value );
```

1. В втором примере кода получаем число
   Прошу объяснить ошибку

P.S Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Когда вы пишете `new Accumulator(1)` — у вас никакой `read` ещё не работает, `this.a`не существует и равен undefined — оттого в value помещается NaN. Когда вы потом пишете `accumulator.read()`, уже слишком поздно: строчка `this.value = 0 + this.a;` давным-давно отработала, в value давным-давно записалось NaN и ваш read не влияет вообще ни на что

Comment: @andreymal  спасибо все понятно, скажите что я наверху написал это относится только js или вообще к программированию (у Вас в профиле нет js только питон) ?